# AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Error with pandas apply
I have a pandas data frame with following columns

```
col = ["File_Path", "Function_Body", "Prediction", "Line_Number"]
```

I am applying get_prediction() function on column Function body and it returns three values

1. List (Prediction): Ex. `[1,1,0,0,0]`
2. List (Confidence): Ex. `[64.000, 88.000,0,0,0]`
3. List of List (Top 5 Tokens with line Number): `[['int', 5], ['ret', 6],['char', 5],['sum', 4],['i', 2]]`

Following piece of code, runs fine for one dataset but gives subjected error for other dataset.

```
final_df["Prediction"],  final_df["Confidence"], final_df["Tokens"] = zip(*final_df["Function_Body"].apply(lambda x:get_prediction(x)))
```

Error:

```
  File "nginx_fast.py", line 404, in <module>
    final_df["Prediction"],  final_df["Confidence"], final_df["Tokens"] = zip(*final_df["Function_Body"].apply(lambda x:get_prediction(x)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2938, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3001, in _set_item
    NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3624, in _set_item
    self._data.set(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1067, in set
    "Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape"
AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape
```

I checked the shape and type of value being returned before return statement, it looks fine to me.

Comment: please post how you called pandas to create a dataframe

Comment: ` col = ["File_Path", "Function_Body", "Prediction", "Line_Number"]  `

`final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)`

Comment: A function  then appends the rows one by one

Comment: `row = []`
`row.append(file_path)`
`row.append(function_body)`
`row.append(np.NaN)`
`row.append(line_number)`
`row = pd.Series(row, index = col)`
 `final_df =  final_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: I don't get it. if the apply method does return 3 lists, why not just use 
...=final_df["Function_Body"].apply(lambda x:get_prediction(x)), what is the point using zip() here?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. This is how I solved it

```
final_df["Prediction"],  final_df["Confidence"], c = zip(*final_df["Function_Body"].apply(lambda x:get_prediction(x)))

final_df["Tokens"] = list(c)
```

because the output 'c' is a tuple, DataFrame should get a list, so you should convert the tuple to a list.